# How can I search a MongoDB of regexes for matches against a given string?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo database that I am accessing via Mongoose and Node.js. The database contains a series of items called `Machine`. Each Machine has a field that is stored as a `String`, but represents a regular expression. We want to take a given String (provided by the user) and check it against all regular expressions in the database to find any potential matches. I know you can search the database via regex with something like this:

```
Machines.find({subject: {$regex: hi}}).exec(function(err, results) {
    // do stuff to results
});
```

But how can I do the reverse of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `$where`:

```
Machines.find({
    $where: 'new RegExp(this.subject).test(' + '"' + string + '") === true'
})
```

also hi greg